# How to select deselect tableview cell in swift4

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I have tableview with cell i want to select and deselect the tableview cell but i am unable do it.

Here is my code:

```
 import UIKit

 class ViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource {

@IBOutlet weak var tableView: UITableView!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return 10
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    var cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell", for: indexPath) as! TableViewCell
    //cell.changeTextField

    return cell
}
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    if let cell = tableView.cellForRow(at: indexPath) as? TableViewCell {
        cell.backgroundColor = UIColor.blue
        print("select")
    }
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didDeselectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    if let cell = tableView.cellForRow(at: indexPath) as? TableViewCell {
        cell.backgroundColor = UIColor.green
        print("deselect")
    }
}
}
```

if i tap on cell i want it to be select and change colour to blue if i again tap on that cell i want to deselect and change colour to green but above my code is not working properly.....
please help me

Comment: Did you set the table view's `delegate`?

Comment: @rmaddy yes i have set

Comment: Are the `didSelectRowAt` and `didDeselectRowAt` methods actually being called?

Answer (score 1):

> select deselect tableview cell in swift5

```py
class UserCardView: UICollectionViewCell {

    @IBOutlet var btnDelete: UIButton!
    @IBOutlet var imgView: UIImageView!
    @IBOutlet var lblUserName: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet var lblBalance: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet var rndView: RoundedView!



    override var isSelected: Bool{
        didSet{
            if self.isSelected
            {
                //This block will be executed whenever the cell’s selection state is set to true 
                self.rndView.backgroundColor = Common.mainColr
                self.lblUserName.textColor = UIColor.white
                self.lblBalance.textColor = UIColor.white
            }
            else
            {
                //This block will be executed whenever the cell’s selection state is set to false 
                self.rndView.backgroundColor = UIColor.white
                self.lblUserName.textColor = UIColor.black
                self.lblBalance.textColor = UIColor.gray
            }
        }
    }


}
```

Answer (score 0):

I have never tried to change the background color, but I have changed cells based on selection. I always do custom classes when I do tableviews so I can handle these kinds of situations easier.  Try this:

class CustomCell: UITableViewCell {

```
override func setSelected(_ selected: Bool, animated: Bool) {
    self.coverView.backgroundColor = selected ? .blue : .green
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

**Swift 5**: Just override isSelected property from your Cell:

```
class SimpleAppCell: UITableViewCell {

// MARK: - Properties

override var isSelected: Bool {
    didSet {
        contentView.backgroundColor = isSelected ? .systemBlue12 : .clear
        contentView.layer.cornerRadius = isSelected ? 8 : 0
        textLabel?.textColor = isSelected ? .systemBlue : .label
    }
}
```